# How to make object follow terrain?

Tags: animation

I have modeled a sled and now I want to animate it going down from mountain, so is there any way to make sled stick to terrain and then animate it going down the mountain?[image]

Comment: Have you checked out rigid body simulations?  http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/quick-tutorial-make-a-wrecking-ball-with-rigid-body-physics/

Comment: Is it possible to control the path sled will take with rigid body simulation?

Comment: Not easily. You could try using a curve constraint, but that will take some trial and error.

Comment: Do you have an empty or bone controlling your sled? If so, you can solve this easily by using a shrinkwrap contraint.

Comment: Hah! Apparently there's an existing solution, but since I already worked another one out (with shrinkwrap constraints and some trigonometry), you might as well use it too. Investigate the center empty's rotation drivers and all the empties' constraints to see how it works: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37958

Comment: just simulate it in the game engine, and mark record animation frames, (you will need to make a physics mesh proxy out of a cube )